# Android app size become increases (almost double) after upgrading from flutter version 3.10.5 to version 3.13.9

Tags: android, flutter, version

After running "flutter build apk --release", the app size seems to be doubled than before. I have upgraded the flutter version and then this happened. any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the build command after flutter Clean

```
flutter clean
```

It reduces the build files for flutter app and the size of the app became less.

It also varies upon architecture of the system depends on 32bit or 64 bit

Note:

if your are trying to build an app .Follow these steps.

For Android bundle:

```
flutter build appbundle --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
```

For Building App:

```
flutter build apk --target-platform android-arm,android-arm64,android-x64
```

Comment: are you referring  split per abi?
I have done that though. It worked fine but when I want to build by running "flutter build apk --release" that's when the size of the app got increased (almost double).